# Comparison of the magnitudes of two normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X, Y$ are two independent random normal variables with mean 0, with distinct variances. Is there an easy way to compute $\mathbb{P}(|X|>|Y|)$?

Comment: Do they have mean zero?

Comment: $|X|>|Y|$ if $X>Y \geq 0$ or $X<Y \leq 0$. Technically you can integrate the joint pdf over these regions but I am not so sure that you will get a closed form solution, even when the means are the same.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are not centered, the result is a mess, if they are the result is $$\frac2\pi\arctan\left(\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}\right)$$

Comment: @Did Yes, I am only interested in the centered case. How do you derive t he answer?

Comment: @user69818 Now that you've been told the result, why don't you try to derive it for yourself?  It is a worthwhile exercise even if you do not succeed.

Comment: @heropup If I knew an easy to way to derive this, I wouldn't ask this question in the first place. This is a step I encountered in my research, and I already knew the answer, via a very lengthy argument. I just would like to know whether there exists a more direct way.

Comment: @user69818 It is strongly advised to provide sufficient context when asking a question on this site, which includes your own efforts to solve the problem.  The solution, as I have shown in my response, is simple and accessible enough to a mathematics undergraduate, but because you do not precisely characterize what you mean by "more direct" nor give any clues as to what you consider to be a sufficiently simple solution, I will assume that my response will be satisfactory to you.

Comment: I should also add that in the future, questions posted without context may be subject to closure and deletion, so please consider this when posting, as it is only polite when requesting assistance from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0, \sigma_X), \quad Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0, \sigma_Y)$$ be independent.  Then clearly $X = \sigma_X Z_X$ and $Y = \sigma_Y Z_Y$ where $Z_X, Z_Y$ are standard normal, and by a trivial symmetry argument, it is immediately obvious that $$\Pr[|X| > |Y|] = \Pr[\sigma_X |Z_X| > \sigma_Y |Z_Y|] = 4\Pr[0 \le Z_Y < m Z_X],$$ where $m = \sigma_X/\sigma_Y$.  Now we integrate:  $$\Pr[|X| > |Y|] = 4 \int_{x=0}^\infty \int_{y=0}^{mx} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)/2} \, dy \, dx.$$  With the substitution $x = r \cos \theta$, $y = r \sin \theta$, the Jacobian of the transformation is $r$, and we obtain $$\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{r=0}^\infty \int_{\theta=0}^{\tan^{-1} m} r e^{-r^2/2} \, dr \, d\theta = \frac{2}{\pi} \tan^{-1} \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}$$ as claimed.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** There are two ways in which simulation might help you to find
an analytic answer. First, it might help to visualize the event $|X| > |Y|.$
Second, it might help you verify your analytic answer when you get it.

@parsaid's question is a good one; the most interesting case could be when
the means are equal. Also, I think you should start by specifying which random variable
has the larger variance $\sigma^2.$

Here is a simulation in R statistical software with $X \sim NORM(\mu = 0, \sigma=10)$ and,
independently, $Y \sim NORM(\mu = 0, \sigma = 5).$ I simulated `m=50,000`
pairs. More would have given a more precise numerical answer (about 70% green points), but
perhaps a less-readable figure.

```
 m = 50000;  x = rnorm(m, 0, 10);  y = rnorm(m, 0, 5)
 cond = (abs(x) > abs(y));  mean(cond)
 ## 0.70556
 plot(x, y, pch=".")
 points(x[cond], y[cond], pch=",", col="green2")
```

[image]

With a million points the probability is $0.705 \pm 0.001$.

Comment: The probability you estimate by simulation is $$\frac2\pi\arctan\left(\frac{10}5\right)\approx0.704832765$$